Data duplication or async on-demand oriented communication on microservices
In our current microservice, we store the data that doesn't belong to us and we persist them all through external events. And we use these duplicate data (that doesn't belong to us) in our actual calculation but I've been thinking what if we replace this duplicate data with async webclient on-demand calls with resilience fallbacks? Everywhere we need the data, we'll call the owner team through APIs. With this way, we'll set us free from maintaining the duplicate data because many times inconsistency happens when the owner team stop publishing the data because of an internal error. In terms of CAP, consistency is more important for us. We can give the responsibility of availability to the data owner team. For why not monolith counter argument, in many companies, there are teams for each service and it's not up to you to design monolith. My question, in this relation, is more about the general company-wide problem. When your service, inevitably, depends on another team's service, is it better to duplicate a data or async on-demand dependency?


When your service, inevitably, depends on another team's service, is it better to duplicate a data or async on-demand dependency?

As usually with architecture questions - answer would be "it depends". The "correct" answer for your case would depend on what trade-off is more acceptable for you.
Data duplication (with some async process of refreshing it via some kind of queue) is a pretty standard way to handle things in microservices architecture in many cases. But in can become stale, as you can observe.
On the other hand directly calling another service API has trade-offs too. First of all due to switching to synchronous communication your services become more tightly coupled with all the possible downsides of that (like unavailability of the service will make your API relying on it fail too, your SLAs will depend on the underlying service SLA's).

We can give the responsibility of availability to the data owner team.

If the other team will guarantee to satisfy the needed SLA/SLO (which is a bit doubtful since you have mentioned that they can't guarantee publishing the data updates) then switching to the synchronous communication seems to be the way to go.

in our actual calculation

For async processes (like background calculations and so on) IMO the default approach is to directly call the service holding the needed data (if the service can handle the load, respond quick enough and so on). So if your calculation is a part of some async process then switching to calling the owner system seems to be the way to go.
See also:

Avoiding Microservice Megadisasters by Jimmy Bogard


Thanks a lot for your answer! So also do you think it would make the system less busy if we call the APIs of the data owner team with batch requests instead of one-by-one?

@Burak As I wrote - there are a lot of things to consider. Without having access to your system and knowing details it is impossible to give a correct answer. In our architecture we have both approaches working just fine, in some cases we prefer data duplication (usually for APIs, but there are cases for async flows too) and in some - direct API calls (usually for async processing, but for APIs sometimes too). Based on VERY limited info you have provided I would consider switching to the API calls with batching.

then I would wonder what would be your conditions to be ok with async on demand option generally? In which cases you would refuse this? I know there are no direct answers but just to know if there are any red flags?

@Burak as I wrote in the answer -  the first and probably the main factor is what flow is using the info from the another service. If this is an async flow (i.e. processing some queue) then I would prefer the directly calling the service. Red flags would be the 1) availability and SLO/SLAs of the service 2) Amounts of data needed and "rates". Also the type of processing is important, i.e. sometimes it is much more beneficial to join/process data on the database side instead of fetching and managing it on the service side.
